# Does Springer publish conference proceedings for free?

Tags: publications, conference, publishers, springer, proceedings

Does Springer publish conference proceedings for free?

It does seem very unlikely given the [significant amount of work](https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/19338528/data/v1) they do to publish the proceedings.

However, I have spent hours reading through their [website](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/conference-proceedings/editors), but there is no mention of any fee.

Could the experienced experts guide me please?

Comment: Are you asking about potential (or lack of) fees for authors or fees for readers?

Comment: @Buffy I am asking about lack of fees for authors and editors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, they publish for free, unless the Open Access option is used (either by the editors of a proceedings volume or by the authors of one particular paper in a proceedings volume).

Their business model relies on subscriptions and (probably to a lesser extent) sales of volumes and individual articles: Universities pay plenty of money for subscriptions, so that they have access to the published volumes. For researchers that publish in Springer, that typically even includes the access to the published versions of their own articles.

Comment: Slight clarification:  the answer is no.  Someone is always paying.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Someone is paying, but not for the act of publishing. The payment is for the act of accessing the published material.